# Math Q&A environment: How to avoid cluttered equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I want to write math questions and answers in the form of a book, which will be read by students. Can someone help me to create question, solution and tips environment, so that I could add the equations every time? Also I don't understand why my equations are cluttered.

I have attached an image about how the solution should look

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%i have used few packages 

\usepackage[margin= 1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}


%document begins here     
    
\begin{document}

%section heading 
\section{Questions on Basic integration}

%question with bold and box 
\begin{tcolorbox}
subsection begins here, the word question should be in bold
\subsection*{Question 1} Solve the following integral. $$\int \sec x(\sec x+\tan x) d x $$ 
\end{tcolorbox}

%solution word in bold
\subsubsection*{Solution}
this is a quick tip, to be highlighted
\textcolor{blue}{$$
\begin{array}{l}
\int \sec ^{2} x d x=\tan x \\
\int \sec x \tan x=\sec x
\end{array}
$$}

%the solution   
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \sec x(&\sec x+\tan x) d x \\
&=\int\left(\sec ^{2} x+\sec x \tan x\right) d x \\
&=\int \sec ^{2} x d x+\int \sec x \tan x d x \\
&=\tan x+\sec x+C
\end{aligned}
$$

%second question
\begin{tcolorbox}

%question 2 begins here 
\subsection*{Question 2} Solve the following integral. $$\int \frac{1}{x+x\log x} dx$$ 
\end{tcolorbox}

%solution in bold
\subsubsection*{Solution}
\textcolor{blue}{$$
\begin{array}{l}
\text { Put } 1+x \log x=t \\
\text { then, } \frac{1}{x}\; d x=d t
\end{array}
 $$}
 % solution begins
\begin{center}$\displaystyle{
\begin{array}{l}
\int \frac{1}{x+x \log x} d x \\
\text { Simce, } \frac{1}{x} d x=d t \text { and }(1+\log x)=t \\
=\int \frac{d t}{t} \\
=\log (t)+C \\
=\int \log (1+\log x)+C
\end{array}
}$ \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use `$$` to initiate and terminate display math mode in a LaTeX document. For more information on this subject, please see [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this? Observe that while I provide code for a macro called `\tip`, I don't define separate question and answer environments, as I think that doing so wouldn't help with the clutter issue. (Actually, these environments might worsen the clutter issue.) I can only recommend that you become more familiar with the multi-line math environments of the `amsmath` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,tcolorbox} 

\newcommand\tip[1]{\smash{\boxed{\color{blue}\array{r} #1 \endarray}}}
\begin{document}

\section{Questions on basic integration}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\subsection*{Question 1} Solve the following integral.
\quad$\displaystyle \int \sec x(\sec x+\tan x)\, dx $
\end{tcolorbox}

\paragraph{Solution}  
\begin{align*}
&\int \sec x(\sec x+\tan x)\, dx 
   \hspace{3cm} \tip{ \int \sec ^{2} x\, dx=\tan x \\[1ex]
                      \int \sec x \tan x \,dx=\sec x} \\
&\quad=\int\bigl(\sec ^{2} x+\sec x \tan x\bigr)\, dx \\
&\quad=\int \sec ^{2} x\, dx+\int \sec x \tan x\, dx \\
&\quad=\tan x+\sec x+C
\end{align*}



\begin{tcolorbox}
\subsection*{Question 2} Solve the following integral. 
\quad$\displaystyle\int \frac{1}{x+x\log x}\,dx$
\end{tcolorbox}

\paragraph{Solution}
\begin{align*}
&\int \frac{1}{x+x \log x}\, dx \\
&\quad= \int \frac{1}{x(1+\log x)}\, dx 
  \hspace{3cm}\tip{\text{\textbf{Tip:} Put } 1+\log x = t \\[1ex]
                   \text{then } \frac{1}{x}\, dx = dt} \\
&\quad=\int \frac{dt}{t} \\
&\quad=\log (t)+C \\
&\quad=\int \log (1+\log x)+C
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address one of the OP's follow-up questions. One could define a `\question` *macro* as follows (in the preamble):

```
\newcommand\question[2]{%
   \tcolorbox 
   \subsection*{Question #1} 
   Solve the following integral.\quad$\displaystyle #2$ 
   \endtcolorbox}
```

and then write `\question{1}{\int \sec x(\sec x+\tan x)\, dx}` in the body of the document.

Comment: +1 for this beautiful and simple formatting!

Comment: @Jes - Many thanks for your compliment!

Comment: and when i use multi columns, the alignment of tip is changing. can i insert tip after solution ?

Comment: @Vinay - You can insert `\tip` anywhere you want. The only condition is that `\tip` has to occur in math mode,

Comment: @Vinay - Have you tried changing `\subsection*{...}` to `\subsection{...}`?

Comment: @Vinay - Why would you want to replace the `\tip` macro with a `tip` environment?

Comment: @Mico sorry its not tip. its question and solution. can we create a macro for question and answer ?

Comment: when i am trying to align in two columns, \tip is not changing its position. can we insert tip right beneath the solution ?

Comment: @Vinay - In my code, the solutions consists of (a) a header (`\paragraph{Solution}`) and (b) a multiline equation; this equation will necessarily be different for each and every solution. If you defined a solution *environment*, it would look like `begin{solution} [[write out equation here ]] \end{solution}` instead of `\paragraph{Solution} [[write out equation here]]`. More work, no discernible benefit.

Comment: @Vinay - Please see the addendum I just posted on how to create a *macro* (not environment) called `\question`.

Comment: @Vinay - On the placement of `\tip` directives: Please see my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to have?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
   \mdfsetup{
      leftmargin=-5,
      rightmargin=-5,
      innerleftmargin=5,% Distance from content to frame.  To align the content with
      innerrightmargin=5,% the surrouding text, the sum of leftmargin and innerleftmargin must be zero.
      linecolor=white,% The frame consists of inner-, middle-, and outerline.  linecolor changes all three.
      innertopmargin=0\topskip,
   }
   \mdtheorem[backgroundcolor=PineGreen!15!white]{tip}{Tip}%[section] % Uncomment if you want to include section number.
   \mdtheorem{quest}{Question}%[section] % Uncomment if you want to include section number.
   \mdtheorem{sol}{Solution}%[section] % Uncomment if you want to include section number.
\newcommand{\dd}[0]{\,\mathrm{d}} % puts a thin space and an upright 'd'.

\begin{document}
 
\section{Questions on Basic integration}
   
   \begin{quest}
      Solve the following integral:
      \begin{equation*}
         \int \sec x(\sec x+\tan x) \dd x.
      \end{equation*}
   \end{quest}%
   %
   \begin{sol*}
      \begin{tip*}
         \begin{align*}
            \int \sec^{2} x \dd x    &= \tan x + C\\
            \int \sec x \tan x \dd x &= \sec x + C
         \end{align*}
      \end{tip*}%
      %
      \begin{align*}
         \int \frac{1}{x+x \log x} \dd x  &= \int\frac{1}{x(1+\log(x))} \dd x\\
         &= \int \frac{\dd t}{t} \\
         &= \log (t)+C \\
         &= \log (1+\log x)+C
      \end{align*}
   \end{sol*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT: As you asked in a comment to have no linebreak after 'Question 1', here is an updated version.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{
   leftmargin=-5,
   rightmargin=-5,
   innerleftmargin=5,% Distance from content to frame.  To align the content with
   innerrightmargin=5,% the surrouding text, the sum of leftmargin and innerleftmargin must be zero.
   linecolor=white,% The frame consists of inner-, middle-, and outerline.  linecolor changes all three.
   innertopmargin=0\topskip,
}

\newtheorem{quest}{Question}   % for numbered questions
\newtheorem*{quest*}{Question} % for unnumbered questions
\newtheorem{tip}{Tip}          % for numbered tips
\newtheorem*{tip*}{Tip}        % for unnumbered tips
\surroundwithmdframed[backgroundcolor=PineGreen!15!white]{tip}  % get the shiny box around (numbered) tips.
\surroundwithmdframed[backgroundcolor=PineGreen!15!white]{tip*} % get the shiny box around (unnumbered) tips.
\newtheorem{sol}{Solution}     % for numbered solutions
\newtheorem*{sol*}{Solution}   % for unnumbered solutions

\newcommand{\dd}[0]{\,\mathrm{d}} % puts a thin space and an upright 'd'.

\begin{document}
   \section{Questions on Basic integration}
   \begin{quest}
      Solve the following integral:
      \begin{equation*}
         \int \sec x(\sec x+\tan x) \dd x.
      \end{equation*}
   \end{quest}%
   %
   \begin{sol*}
      ~ % For some reason the tip-environment covers the word 'solution' when there is nothing between them.
      \begin{tip*} Here can be some text.
         \begin{align*}
            \int \sec^{2} x \dd x    &= \tan x + C\\
            \int \sec x \tan x \dd x &= \sec x + C
         \end{align*}
      \end{tip*}%
      %
      \begin{align*}
         \int \frac{1}{x+x \log x} \dd x  &= \int\frac{1}{x(1+\log(x))} \dd x\\
         &= \int \frac{\dd t}{t} \\
         &= \log (t)+C \\
         &= \log (1+\log x)+C
      \end{align*}
   \end{sol*}
\end{document}
```